# Display real-time variables values in a Gui in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, real-time

I want to make a windows that will shoes the values of a variable in real-time in python with tkinter. The variable in question will be in a while loop. This is for a small physics project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that questions simply asking for code are often frowned upon here. You'll find that people are more willing to help if you provide more detail on what you've already tried. You can check the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on what constitutes a good question. You can click the "edit" button in the lower-left of your post to update information.

Answer (score 0):

OK you haven't been very clear on exactly what your doing, but if you are going to update in a while loop you would do something such as getting whatever variable and then setting a variable on a label presumably.

```
import tkinter, time
from tkinter import *

#declare vars for readability
var1 = StringVar()
velocityOfBall = 0
gravity = 9.8

root = Tk()

def startDemo():
    while True:
        velocityOfBall += gravity
        var1.set("Velocity: " + velocityOfBall)
        time.sleep(1)

button1 = Button(root, command=startDemo).grid(row=0, column=0)
label1 = Label(root, textvariable = var1).grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: calling `time.sleep` should be avoided at all costs in the main thread of a GUI application. This is definitely not a very good solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley I only added that to make it so gravity changed once every second I wasn't recommending that it sleep in a full application, it just met the proposes for gravity And making my gravity affect the ball once every second